# How to merge two json object into an array in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures, merge, jsonb

I have two jsonb value. I would like to merge it however I stuck to combine it together. This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emr.azintin(p_msg text)
 RETURNS character varying
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_msgar     text[];
    v_msgln     text;
    v_currusr   afm_usr.user_id%type := 'SYSEXCH';
    v_currdt    afm_usr.insert_date%type := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    macres      azt_macres%rowtype;
    orddet      lbt_orddet%rowtype;
    v_resultid  character varying ;
    v_reading   character varying ;

BEGIN   
         v_msgar := array['OBR||||^^^3972^2102001420||||20210227133222|25||||3
                            OBX|||0^RBC||4.99|^10â¶/Î¼L|3.85-5.78||||F
                            OBX|||1^HGB||14.4|^g/dL|12.0-17.2||||F
                            OBX|||2^MCV||84.5|^fL|78.0-96.0||||F
                            OBX|||3^HCT||42.2|^%|34.8-50.9||||F
                            OBX|||4^MCH||28.90|^pg|26.40-33.20||||F
                            OBX|||5^MCHC||34.2|^g/dL|31.8-36.7|||<EOT>|F
                            OBX|||6^RDWsd||39.2|^fL|0.0-0.0||||F'];
              
            SELECT json_agg(jsonb_build_object('resultValue',split_part(parts[6],'^',1)))
               INTO v_reading
               FROM unnest(v_msgar) as elem,
                     regexp_split_to_array(elem, '\|') as parts
               WHERE parts[1] = 'OBX';
              
            SELECT json_agg(jsonb_build_object('resultId',split_part(parts[4],'^',2)))
               INTO v_resultid
               FROM unnest(v_msgar) as elem,
                     regexp_split_to_array(elem, '\|') as parts
               WHERE parts[1] = 'OBX';
              
            select concat(v_resultid || v_reading) 
               INTO macres.test_result
               FROM unnest(v_msgar) as elem,
                     regexp_split_to_array(elem, '\|') as parts
               WHERE parts[1] = 'OBX';
        
            SELECT split_part(items[5], '^', 5)
                  INTO macres.specimen_id
                FROM (
                  SELECT string_to_array(element, '|') as items
                 FROM unnest(v_msgar) as t(element)) t   
            WHERE items[1] = 'OBR';
    

    END IF;
END
$function$
;
```

I manage to get the v_reading and v_resultid which look like this

```
 [{"resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultValue": "14.2"}, {"resultValue": "81.7"}, {"resultValue": "42.5"}, {"resultValue": "27.20"}, {"resultValue": "33.3"}, {"resultValue": "40.6"}, {"resultValue": "15.9"}, {"resultValue": "188"}, {"resultValue": "8.1"}, {"resultValue": "0.15"}, {"resultValue": "9.4"}, {"resultValue": "46.2"}, {"resultValue": "4.6"}, {"resultValue": "1.1"}, {"resultValue": "23.6"}, {"resultValue": "0.4"}, {"resultValue": "8.7"}, {"resultValue": "3.1"}, {"resultValue": "67.7"}, {"resultValue": "56"}, {"resultValue": "105"}, {"resultValue": ""}]
```

```
[{"resultId": "RBC"}, {"resultId": "HGB"}, {"resultId": "MCV"}, {"resultId": "HCT"}, {"resultId": "MCH"}, {"resultId": "MCHC"}, {"resultId": "RDWsd"}, {"resultId": "RDWcv"}, {"resultId": "PLT"}, {"resultId": "MPV"}, {"resultId": "PCT"}, {"resultId": "PDWsd"}, {"resultId": "PDWcv"}, {"resultId": "WBC"}, {"resultId": "LYM"}, {"resultId": "LYMP"}, {"resultId": "MID"}, {"resultId": "MIDP"}, {"resultId": "GRA"}, {"resultId": "GRAP"}, {"resultId": "PLCR"}, {"resultId": "PLCC"}, {"resultId": "RBCHistogram"}]
```

how can i combine these two json to look like these

```
[{"resultid": "RBC", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "HGB", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "MCV", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "HCT", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "MCH", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "MCHC", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "RDWsd", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "RDWcv", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "PLT", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "MPV", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "PCT", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "PDWsd", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "PDWcv", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "WBC", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "LYM", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "LYMP", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "MID", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "MIDP", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "GRA", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "GRAP", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "PLCR", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "PLCC", "resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultid": "RBCHistogram", "resultValue": "5.20"}]
```

I can simply do like these

```
            SELECT json_agg(jsonb_build_object('resultid',split_part(parts[4],'^',2), 'resultValue',split_part(parts[6],'^',1)))
               INTO macres.test_result
               FROM unnest(v_msgar) as elem,
                     regexp_split_to_array(elem, '\|') as parts
               WHERE parts[1] = 'OBX';
```

but the problem is I need to put a condition in split_part(parts[4],'^',2) thats why i seperate it into v_reading and v_resultid.

I want to put condition

```
IF v_resultid = 'MCHC' THEN
   v_reading = null
END ID
```

But somehow it still put the reading if the array found MCHC. I want to remove MCHC from my json

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing here. The JSON values do not fit your array, the array is not valid... So, two options here: Do you want us to write an entire query (which, I already did several times on your previous questions) - I would to this in one query, not in seperated... Or do you just want to know how to merge both JSON objects. Then please remove the entire confusing code to minimize your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both JSON objects:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6afca2cbaa1b7a8cb0dc2af37da180ed)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(a.element || b.element)                        -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(                      -- 1
        '[{"resultValue": "5.20"}, {"resultValue": "14.2"}, {"resultValue": "81.7"}, {"resultValue": "42.5"}, {"resultValue": "27.20"}, {"resultValue": "33.3"}, {"resultValue": "40.6"}, {"resultValue": "15.9"}, {"resultValue": "188"}, {"resultValue": "8.1"}, {"resultValue": "0.15"}, {"resultValue": "9.4"}, {"resultValue": "46.2"}, {"resultValue": "4.6"}, {"resultValue": "1.1"}, {"resultValue": "23.6"}, {"resultValue": "0.4"}, {"resultValue": "8.7"}, {"resultValue": "3.1"}, {"resultValue": "67.7"}, {"resultValue": "56"}, {"resultValue": "105"}, {"resultValue": ""}]'::jsonb
    ) WITH ORDINALITY as a(element, index)                   -- 2
) a
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(
        '[{"resultId": "RBC"}, {"resultId": "HGB"}, {"resultId": "MCV"}, {"resultId": "HCT"}, {"resultId": "MCH"}, {"resultId": "MCHC"}, {"resultId": "RDWsd"}, {"resultId": "RDWcv"}, {"resultId": "PLT"}, {"resultId": "MPV"}, {"resultId": "PCT"}, {"resultId": "PDWsd"}, {"resultId": "PDWcv"}, {"resultId": "WBC"}, {"resultId": "LYM"}, {"resultId": "LYMP"}, {"resultId": "MID"}, {"resultId": "MIDP"}, {"resultId": "GRA"}, {"resultId": "GRAP"}, {"resultId": "PLCR"}, {"resultId": "PLCC"}, {"resultId": "RBCHistogram"}]'::jsonb
    ) WITH ORDINALITY as b(element, index)
) b
ON a.index = b.index                                         -- 3
```

1. Extract the JSON arrays into one row per element.
2. The `WITH ORDINALITY` adds a row count to each expanded record to identify the original position in the array
3. Join both extracted JSON element sets on the index
4. Merge both JSON columns using the `||` operator (works only with type `jsonb` noth with type `json`, which should be used nonetheless). Finally you can aggregate these merged objects into a new JSON array.